# Is there any sandbox environment for Twitter app development?

Tags: ios, twitter, sandbox, sharekit

I am developing an iOS application and I am integrating the ShareKit 2.0 project. I want to share content via Facebook and Twitter. Both of them require to create an application on their platform. Everything at this point is ok.

The problem is that as the application in under development, we don't want it to be visible by anybody that is not in this project, so we can't publish content on our facebook/twitter accounts visibly for external people.

Facebook supports a sandbox environment where the app admin can allow just certain users to use the application, so only those users will be able to access and view contents related with that app. And I am looking for something similar on Twitter, but I can't find it.

This is a very hard problem, when you don't find out if this is possible or not, because you never know when you should stop looking for the answer and decide it's not possible. So here I am, asking to SO gurus: is there any sandbox environment for Twitter so we can develop and test our applications?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as I received no answer for this question, I will finally deduce that there does not exist such a sandbox environment for Twitter.

However, I "solved" my requirements by setting my testing account in private mode (I didn't know about this because I rarely use Twitter). Right now this will do the trick, but of course it's much worse than the Facebook sandbox environment.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1238

> @episod Taylor Singletary
>   There are unfortunately no sandboxes for this kind of activity. It's best for automated testing to not actually hit the API but instead to mock it out.

I recommend you just create a dummy account for testing. I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://twitsandbox.com

twitSandbox is a web application to support creating applications using the Twitter APIs. It actually processes the methods of almost all and you can confirm what kind of response receives.